# how can I create a content provider which every other app can read but none can write?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I understand that export=true will set the content provider to be readable and writable by all other apps. But now I only want content provider to be readable by everyone but writable by no one. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this problem would be creating two `ContentProviders`. The exported one would have only the implementation of the `query()` method, the `insert()`, `update()`, and `delete()`.

The second one (private), would not be exported and it would contain the implementation of all the methods. You could use inheritance to avoid repetition of the code.

---

You'd have to register them both in the **AndroidManifest.xml**. Keep in mind that the `ContentProviders` would have to have different `authorities` but they can still operate on the same data.